# Number theory divisibility problem

Tags: number-theory

For an integer $n > 1$, prove that
$2^n - 1$ does not divide $ 3^n - 1$.

I tried doing it for primes first, but got no where. I think we might get it if we assume $k$ to be the smallest integer such that the divisibility holds, and then try to get a contradiction.

Comment: If $n$ is even, then $2^n-1$ is a multiple of 3...

Comment: I found a nice solution with quadratic reciprocity, but probably there are easier ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by Michael in the comments, if $n$ is even $2^n-1$ is a multiple of three, so we may assume $n=2m+1$ with $m\geq 1$. Assuming that a prime number $p>3$ divides both $2^{2m+1}-1$ and $3^{2m+1}-1$, then $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{12}$ and $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{8}$, since:
$$ 2\cdot 4^m \equiv 3\cdot 9^m \equiv 1\pmod{p} $$
imply that both $2$ and $3$ are quadratic residues $\pmod{p}$. However,
$$ 2^{2m+1}-1 \equiv 7\pmod{12}, $$
so it is not possible that *every* prime $p>3$ that divides $2^{2m+1}-1$ is $\equiv \pm 1\pmod{12}$, hence $2^{2m+1}-1$ cannot divide $3^{3m+1}-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider two cases:

$1)$ $n$ is even, therefore we can write $n=2m$ (with $m$ integer) and the expression $\frac {3^n-1}{2^n-1}= k$ (with $k$ integer) becomes $$\frac {9^m-1}{4^m-1}= k$$  but we can write $$\frac {8(9^{m-1}+9^{m-2}+...+9+1)}{3(4^{m-1}+4^{m-2}+....+4+1)}=k$$
this equation hasn't solutions in integers. Indeed $8\equiv 2\pmod 3$ and $9^{m-1}+9^{m-2}+...+9+1\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

$2)$ $n$ is odd, therefore we can write $n=2m+1$ and the equation becomes $$\frac {3^{2m+1}-1}{2^{2m+1}-1}= k$$ and rewriting the quation: $$\frac {9^{m+\frac{1}{2}}-1}{4^{m+\frac{1}{2}}-1}=k$$ and then we can write $$\frac {3\cdot 9^m-1}{2\cdot 4^m-1}=k$$ and multiplying the numerator and denominator for $2$ we obtain:$$\frac {6\cdot 9^{m}-1}{4^{m+1}-1}=k$$ and  rewriting the equation we obtain: $$\frac {6\cdot(9^m-\frac{1}{6})}{3\cdot(4^{m}+4^{m-1}+....+1)}=k$$ and  rewriting $$\frac {53\cdot (9^{m-1}\cdot 6^{m-1}+9^{m-2}\cdot 6^{m-2}+...+9\cdot 6+1)}{3\cdot(4^{m}+4^{m-1}+....+1)\cdot 6^{m-1}}=k$$ but this equation hasn't solutions. Indeed $3$ isn't a divisor of $53$ and of $9^{m-1}\cdot 6^{m-1}+9^{m-2}\cdot 6^{m-2}+...+9\cdot 6+1$.

## Little curiosity

Considering the equation$$\frac {9^{m+1}-1}{6\cdot (4^m-\frac {1}{6})}=k$$ therefore rewriting the equation:$$\frac {8(9^m+9^{m-1}+...9+1)}{23(4^{m-1}+4^{m-2}\frac {1}{6}+....+\frac {1}{6^{m-1}})}=k$$ but the only values that are multiple $23$ are multiple of $10$,$m=10q$ (with $q$ integer). Indeed $$9^2\equiv 12\pmod {23}, 9^3\equiv 16\pmod {23},9^4\equiv 6\pmod {23},9^5\equiv 8, 9^6\equiv 3, 9^7\equiv 4, 9^8\equiv 13, 9^9\equiv 2, 9^{10}\equiv 18$$ and $$1+9+9^2+9^3+9^4+9^5+9^6+9^7+9^8+9^9+9^{10}$$ is a multiple of $23$. Therefore the only values that are multiple of $23$ are $10q$ $m=10q$ but we had demonsrated that these values aren't acceptable.

Comment: It is not crystal clear to me, especially the part *"if $m$ is even, $m+\frac{1}{2}$ is an integer"* ?!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I did a mistake but now I edited my answer

Comment: (-1) I still don't get it. $9^m-\frac{1}{6}\neq 9^m-\frac{1}{6^\color{red}{m}}$, so what kind of expansion are you applying?